# как сдвинуть рамку блока

Tags: html, css

Изменение границ блока не помогает. Нужно чтобы нижняя рамка левых блоков была на одной высоте с рамкой правых блоков.

```css
.about-exemple-second:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-bottom: solid  3px;
}
.about-exemple:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-right: solid 3px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px;
}
.about-exemple {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
}
.about-exemple-second {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 303px;
    left: 353px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="about-exemple"><p>текст</p></div>
            <div class="about-exemple"><p>текст</p></div>
            <div class="about-exemple"><p>текст</p></div>
            <div class="about-exemple-second"><p>текст</p></div>
            <div class="about-exemple-second"><p>текст</p></div>
            <div class="about-exemple-second"><p>текст</p></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда сдвинуть? Какую границу? Нужно больше подробностей и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: У Вас один из закрывающих тегов p битый

Answer (score 2):

у блока `<p>` по умолчанию всегда есть внешние отступы `margin`, которые вам и портят всё позиционирование, вылезая за пределы родительских `<div>`.
Исправляется просто: либо у всех `<p>` принудительно убираем `margin`, либо родительским `<div>` задаем хотя бы минимальный `padding`.

```css
.about-exemple-second:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
}

.about-exemple:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: solid 3px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px;
}

.about-exemple {
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-exemple-second {
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 300px;
  left: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}


/*p {
  margin: 0;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="about-exemple">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
<div class="about-exemple">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
<div class="about-exemple">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
<div class="about-exemple-second">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
<div class="about-exemple-second">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
<div class="about-exemple-second">
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
```